# Parsing Tokens in a Toy Interpreter

Tags: c++, homework

I'm working on a homework writing a toy interpreter. All the expressions in this language are prefix expressions. The language has a lot of lexical tokens and I wrote code as follows:

```cpp
Value *expression() {
    std::string token;
    cin >> token;

    if (token == "make")
        return make();
    else if (token == "thing")
        return thing();
    else if (token == "print")
        return print();
    else if (token == "read")
        return read();
    else if (token == "add")
        return new Number(*expression() + *expression());
    else if (token == "sub")
        return new Number(*expression() - *expression());
    else if (token == "mul")
        return new Number(*expression() * *expression());
    else if (token == "div")
        return new Number(*expression() / *expression());
    else if (token == "mod")
        return new Number(int(*expression()) % int(*expression()));
    else if (token == "true")
        return new Bool(true);
    else if (token == "false")
        return new Bool(false);
    else if (token[0] == '"')       // String
        return new Word(token.substr(1));
    else if (token[0] == ':')
        return thing(token.substr(1));
    else                            // Number
        return new Number(std::stod(token));
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            auto res = expression();
        } catch (const std::exception &e) {
            std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I think it's kind of ugly to have such a long (and will be longer) if-else chain, and maybe it will cost much time to compare along this chain. I don't know whether there will be some optimizations done by the compiler.

I'm wondering if I have some better way to organize my code, or is this if-else chain method already good enough?

The complete compilable code is:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Value {
public:
    virtual operator double() = 0;
    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};

class Number : public Value {
    double value;

public:
    Number(double d) : value(d) {}
    operator double() { return value; }
    std::string toString() { return std::to_string(value); }
};

class Word : public Value {
    std::string value;

public:
    Word(const std::string &str) : value(str) {}
    Word(std::string &&str) : value(str) {}
    operator double() { return std::stod(value); }
    std::string get() { return value; }
    std::string toString() { return value; }
};

class Bool : public Value {
    bool value;

public:
    Bool(bool b) : value(b) {}
    Bool(const std::string &str) {
        if (str == "true")
            value = true;
        else if (str == "false")
            value = false;
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument{str + " is not a valid Bool value"};
    }
    operator double() { throw std::invalid_argument{"Bool is not convertable to Number。"}; }
    std::string toString() { return value ? "true" : "false"; }
};

template <typename T, typename U> T downcastOrDie(U *ptr) {
    auto res = dynamic_cast<T>(ptr);
    if (!res) throw std::invalid_argument{"dynamic cast failed"};
    return res;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, Value *> symbolTbl;

void program();
Value *expression();
Value *make();
Value *thing();
Value *thing(const std::string &name);
Value *print();
Value *read();


Value *expression() {
    std::string token;
    cin >> token;

    if (token == "make")
        return make();
    else if (token == "thing")
        return thing();
    else if (token == "print")
        return print();
    else if (token == "read")
        return read();
    else if (token == "add")
        return new Number(*expression() + *expression());
    else if (token == "sub")
        return new Number(*expression() - *expression());
    else if (token == "mul")
        return new Number(*expression() * *expression());
    else if (token == "div")
        return new Number(*expression() / *expression());
    else if (token == "mod")
        return new Number(int(*expression()) % int(*expression()));
    else if (token == "true")
        return new Bool(true);
    else if (token == "false")
        return new Bool(false);
    else if (token[0] == '"') // String
        return new Word(token.substr(1));
    else if (token[0] == ':')
        return thing(token.substr(1));
    else // Number
        return new Number(std::stod(token));
}

Value *make() {
    auto name = expression();
    auto value = expression();
    symbolTbl[downcastOrDie<Word *>(name)->get()] = value;
    return value;
}

Value *thing() { return thing(downcastOrDie<Word *>(expression())->get()); }

Value *thing(const std::string &name) { return symbolTbl[name]; }

Value *print() {
    auto val = expression();
    cout << val->toString() << endl;
    return val;
}

bool isDouble(const std::string &str) {
    bool hasDecimalPoint = false;
    if (str.length() == 0) return false;

    auto it = str.begin();
    if (*it == '-') ++it;

    for (; it != str.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == '.') {
            if (hasDecimalPoint)
                return false;
            else
                hasDecimalPoint = true;
        } else if (!std::isdigit(*it))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Value *read() {
    std::string input;
    cin >> input;

    if (isDouble(input)) {
        return new Number(std::stod(input));
    } else {
        return new Word(input);
    }
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            auto res = expression();
        } catch (const std::exception &e) {
            std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo Could you please give me some more information? Should I make a map from string to something like std::function? Is it a good practice considering factors such as maintainability, readability, and efficiency?

Comment: That is one way. Or you can return an integer (enum) that you `switch` on. Or you can return a label that you `goto` (don’t do that one though). Though looking at your list, which contains different levels of operants and expressions, it seems to me you need to re-read the chapter on parsing in your programming book. Actually we don’t write parsers by hand, that process was already automated back in the 1970’s (with `yacc`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not all languages can be parsed by yacc parsers. [Recursive decent parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) can be easily written by hand in many programming languages, and it's a nice learning experience. Parser generators are indeed the way to go for serious projects, but you then have to learn how to write your language's grammar in a format that the parser generator understands, and sometimes fight with proper integration of the generated code into your own project.

Comment: Use `flex` and `bison` to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use a look-up table

As already mentioned by Cris Luengo in the comments, you can avoid the long `if-else` sequence by using a look-up table. You want to map tokens to functions that will do the processing related to that token. It can look like:

```
using action_type = std::function<Value*(std::string_view)>;

static std::unordered_map<std::string, action_type> actions = {
    {"make",  [](auto){ return make(); }},
    {"thing", [](auto){ return thing(); }},
    …
    {"add",   [](auto){ return new Number(*expression() + *expression()); }},
    …
    {":",     [](auto token){ return thing(token.substr(1)); }},
};
```

And then `expression()` can be simplified to:

```
Value *expression() {
    std::string token;
    cin >> token;

    if (auto action = actions.find(token); action != actions.end()) {
        return action(token);
    } else /* Number */ {
        return new Number(std::stod(token));
    }
}
```

It will be faster too, since a [`std::unordered_map()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) uses a hash table to look up the token in \$O(1)\$ time, whereas your code has to check the token against all possible values.

## Avoid manual memory management

Avoid calling `new` and `delete` manually in your code. It's easy to forget to call `delete` and to introduce a memory leak that way. For example, in just this piece of code:

```
*expression() + *expression()
```

You leaked two memory allocations. Instead, use [`std::unique_ptr<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to store your pointers in; it will automatically delete the storage when the pointer is going out of scope:

```
std::unique_ptr<Value> make();

using action_type = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Value>(std::string_view)>;

static std::unordered_map<std::string, action_type> actions = {
    {"make",  [](auto){ return make(); }},
    …
    {"add",   [](auto){
        return std::make_unique<Number>(*expression() + *expression());
    }},
    …
};

std::unique_ptr<Value> expression() {
    …
    return action(token);
    …
}
```

Now the memory leak in the addition expression is gone.

## Consider using `std::variant` to store values

You are using inheritance to be able to pass around `Value`s of different types. This is fine, but one drawback is that you have to allocate each `Value` in some way, because you can only pass it around using pointers. That can result in your code making lots of memory allocations. A different way to do this is to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which will allow you to pass `Value`s by value (no pun intended). The code would look like:

```
class Number /* no inheritance */ {
    double value;
public:
    /* same members as before */
    …
};
…
using Value = std::variant<Number, Word, Bool>;

Value make();

using action_type = std::function<Value(std::string_view)>;

static std::unordered_map<std::string, action_type> actions = {
    {"make",  [](auto){ return make(); }},
    …
    {"add",   [](auto){ return expression() + expression(); }},
    …
}

Value expression() {
    …
    return action(token);
    …
}
```

Notice how convenient it is to no longer have to deal with `Value`s being passed around as pointer! Of course, now you still have to deal with how to add two `Value`s together. But how does addition work now? If you could only add `Number`s together, it could look like this:

```
Value operator+(const Value& lhs_value, const Value& rhs_value) {
    double lhs = std::get<Number>(lhs_value);
    double rhs = std::get<Number>(rhs_value);
    return Number(lhs + rhs);
}
```

Note that `std::get<Number>(lhs_value)` will throw an exception if `lhs` was a `Word` or a `Bool`. Alternatively, you can use [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
Value operator+(const Value& lhs_value, const Value& rhs_value) {
    return std::visit([](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) {
        return lhs + rhs;
    }, lhs_value, rhs_value);
}
```

This basically unpacks the `Value`s, so the lambda is called with the concrete types (`Number`, `Word` and/or `Bool`). It then relies on `operator+()` existing for those types.

## Be careful with string to double conversion

All the standard library functions that deal with conversion from strings to numbers, like [`std::stod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), will ignore any non-number characters that occur after the number. So `std::stod("123four")` will return `123`, and will not throw an exception. Consider using [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) instead, as it reports how far it read, and then check that it read the whole string.

## I/O can fail at any time

Be aware that any input/output operations can fail at any time, even `std::cin` and `std::cout`: maybe the user closed the terminal, or pressed ctrl-D (on UNIX). If you don't handle this, your program will go into an infinite loop reading empty strings. In `read()` for example, I recommend you add:

```
if (!std::cin.good()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error reading input");
}
```

And of course, in `main()` you should know when exceptions are fatal, and break out of the `while(true)` loop when it is.

Comment: Thank you for the review! I've tried to accept the advices, and my new code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xde54vr8n). Sorry for being unclear, the language is a weak typed language where `Word`s can be implicitly converted into `Number`s or `Bool`s when needed. So I use `Value` class with a `std::variant` as a member, so that I can create implicit conversion more easily. I'm not sure whether there are more possible improvements, but I'll post a follow up question when I add more features.

Comment: Great, we're looking forward to the follow-up question :)